# Thinking in Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

I know Ramda have full of useful functions, but i don't know, how to compose it better then this. Can anyone do this better please? 
PS. Some reference to how think in Ramda would be fine.

```
// @flow
/**
  const state = {
    forms: [
      {id: 'form-id'}
    ],
    inputs: [
      {inputId: 'input-id', formId: 'form-id', value: ''}
    ]
  }
*/


import { propEq, find, update, compose, assoc, assocPath, findIndex } from 'ramda';

export const setInputValueInState = (
  inputId: string,
  value: string,
  state: FormsState,
): FormsState => {
  const input = getInputById(inputId, state);
  const inputWithNewValue = assoc('value', value, input);
  const inputIndex = findIndex(propEq('inputId', inputId))(state.inputs);
  return assocPath(['inputs', inputIndex], inputWithNewValue, state);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could go with this.  With some clever use of [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) or [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), you could probably create a point-free version of your existing function.  I don't think it would end up being particularly readable, though, and so I would look to other techniques.

One possibility is to use `lenses`.  Most articles on lenses are for Haskell or other languages.  But I found a few in Javascript by [A. Sharif](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/an-introduction-into-lenses-in-javascript-e494948d1ea5), [Drew Tipson](https://medium.com/@dtipson/functional-lenses-d1aba9e52254), and [Vladimir Gorej](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/functional-lenses-javascript-vladim%C3%ADr-gorej/)

Ramda has several built-in lens-creating functions, [`lensProp`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp), [`lensPath`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath), and [`lensIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensIndex), as well as functions like [`view`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#view), [`set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set), and [`over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) to work with lenses.  But it's easy enough to create your own, such as `inputIdLens` below.

```js
const state = {
  forms: [
    {id: 'form-id'}
  ],
  inputs: [
    {inputId: 'i-1', formId: 'foo-12', value: '123'},
    {inputId: 'i-2', formId: 'bar-34', value: '234'},
    {inputId: 'i-3', formId: 'baz-56', value: '345'},
    {inputId: 'i-4', formId: 'qux-78', value: '456'},
    {inputId: 'i-5', formId: 'corge-90', value: '567'}
  ]
}

const {lens, find, propEq, update, findIndex, set, compose, lensProp} = R

const inputIdLens = (inputId) => lens(
  (s) => find(propEq('inputId', inputId), s),
  (a, s) => update(findIndex(propEq('inputId', inputId), s), a, s)
)

const setInputValueInState = (inputId, val, state) => 
  set(compose(lensProp('inputs'), inputIdLens(inputId), lensProp('value')), val, state)

console.log(setInputValueInState('i-2', 'foobar', state))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Scott's answer feels more functional, I find this approach easier to write and understand. I favour `evolve` over lenses, feels more natural IMO.

```
import { curry, evolve, adjust, findIndex, propEq, assoc } from 'ramda';

const state = {
  forms: [
    {id: 'form-id'}
  ],
  inputs: [
    {inputId: 'i-1', formId: 'form-1', value: '123'},
    {inputId: 'i-2', formId: 'form-2', value: '234'},
  ]
}

const setInputValueInState = curry((inputId, value, obj) => evolve({
  inputs: adjust(
    findIndex(propEq('inputId', inputId), obj.inputs), 
    assoc('value', value),
  ),
}, obj));

setInputValueInState('i-2', 'foobar', state);
```